# Verify and Publish in BSC Scan not working

Tags: tokens, bsc, verify, contract-verification

I have a contract, where I compiled it optimized in 200. When I go to publish in BSC Scan, it gives me some messages as attached. I'm informing in bsc scan the optimization in 200.

[image]

It points out something about libraries, but each and every library or interface being used is contained in the single file.
In the comparison he makes of the bytecodes, he says it doesn't match. But I took the two bytecodes and compared them to an online comparator, and it's exactly the same. Compare the image with item 8.

[image]

What could be happening?

Comment: Try to use  the library of hardhat to do that.

Comment: is it an ide? Can I build for BSC? @MajdTL

Answer (score 1):

Bsscan is not very friendly when it comes to publishing contracts, it can go wrong for an extra step or even misplaced comments.

for a better verification, and if you are using Truffle for development or testing, you can download the [verification plugin](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) and use that to verify.  For this, you will also need to have an account at `bsscan` and get an API key (which is free).

After installing `truffle-plugin-verify`, and in your `truffle-config.js` file add the following attributes :

```
plugins: [
        'truffle-plugin-verify'
    ],
    api_keys: {
        bscscan: "" // the API key you get from bsscan
    }
```

then to verify the contract you simply run the following command

```
truffle run verify someTokenName --network=NameOfyourNetwork
```

you can add `--debug` to see the inner steps taken.

more details in this article from [openZepplin](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/bscscan-unable-to-generate-contract-bytecode-and-abi/7279)